# How to ring the phone(Or make some sound)

Tags: android

I am developing an app which requires the phone to  ring or make some sound when user click on some button or a particular event occur.
What will be the code for that.
I tried to find it and found some code to ring the phone with  notifications.
But I dont want that.
I just need to ring the phone when user clicks a button.
Do i need to store some sound file in resource folder as well.

Comment: use media player for playing sounds....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `SoundPool` for which there is a [great tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html#tutorial_soundpool). and yes, you'll store the sound file as a resource.

Comment: in which file we have to add the sound(as resource) file.

Comment: referring to the tutorial I mentioned, the resource `R.raw.sound1` refers to a file called `sound1.ogg` located in the `res/raw` directory.

Comment: you could use `Thread.sleep` to delay and then _in the UI thread_ call `soundPool.play` again.